# Intersection of two sets which are equivalence on set A is always equivalence?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

If $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are equivalence relations on set A ,then$ R_{1}\bigcap R_{2}$ must be equivalence relation.

firstly, I am not understanding the function of **R**,I think that, this is only a relation (according to me) how can it be an equivalence it's not a set.I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 hrs now I lift up my hands.

Comment: Equivalence relations or equivalence classes?

Comment: @SalmonKiller Equivalence relations

Comment: This doesn't make sense then. It's using set operators on relations.

Comment: @SalmonKiller I  perfectly copy down this question.

Comment: Are you sure they are not implying equivalence classes? Maybe $R$ is a set defined by the equivalence relation?

Comment: $(a,a) \in R_1$ and $(a,a) \in R_1$ then $(a,a) \in R_1 \cap R_2$. and so on...

Comment: @user1 $R$ is not a set by the definition given by the OP.

Comment: but R is not a set.

Comment: @SalmonKiller YES

Comment: @SalmonKille R is not a set it is a relation.

Comment: @Sharma: A relation *is* a set. See my answer.

Comment: @ celtschk Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> firstly, I am not understanding the function of R,I think that, this is only a relation (according to me) how can it be an equivalence it's not a set.

A relation $R$ is a set of pairs, $R\subseteq A\times A$.
$aRb$ is just a short form to write $(a,b)\in R$.

Now if we define $R=R_1\cap R_2$, we have
$$\begin{align}
aRb &\iff (a,b)\in R &&\text{(expansion of short form)}\\
&\iff (a,b)\in R_1\cap R_2 &&\text{(definition of R)}\\
&\iff (a,b)\in R_1\land (a,b)\in R_2 &&\text{(definition of intersection)}\\
&\iff aR_1b\land aR_2b &&\text{(rewrite back into short form)}
\end{align}$$

So your task is to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation, that is, is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.